# Existence of Solutions for the Dirichlet Problem Using Subharmonic Functions

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I was reading the Partial Differential Equations book by Fritz John. In this book, I came across proof of the Existence of Solutions for the Dirichlet Problem Using Subharmonic Functions. This technique is also known as "**Perron's Method**". As this technique is divided among various parts, I was able to understand few but struck on this lemma:

**Lemma VI:** $w_f$ is harmonic in $\Omega$,
where $\Omega$ is bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Define $$w_f(x) = \sup_{u \in \sigma_f(\bar{\Omega})} \quad \text{for x} \in \Omega$$
and 
$$\sigma_f(\bar{\Omega}) = \{u: u \in C^0(\bar\Omega) \cap \sigma(\Omega), u \le f \quad \text{on} \quad \partial \Omega\} $$

In the proof written by the author, they stated that,
Let $x^1,x^2,....$ be a sequence of point in some ball say $B(\xi,\rho)$, by the definition of $w_f$ we can find functions $u^j_k \in \sigma_f(\bar{\Omega})$ for $k,j=1,2,3 \dots$ such that
$$ \lim_{j \to \infty} u^j_k (x^k)= w_f (x^k)$$

My question is how we are getting $u^j_k \in \sigma_f(\bar{\Omega})$ from the definition of $w_f$. I have some intuition that it is coming from the compactness property of the domain but still not so clear.